# How to delete all but one file in Unix?

Tags: unix, rm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to delete all files in a directory except some?](https://superuser.com/questions/529854/how-to-delete-all-files-in-a-directory-except-some)

How to delete all but one(or some) file in Unix?

Something like

```
 rm -rf -ignore myfile.txt *
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
ls * | grep -v dont_delete_this_file | xargs rm -rf
```

Example :

```
mkdir test && cd test
touch test1
touch test2
touch test3
touch test4
touch test5
```

To remove all files except 'test2' :

```
ls * | grep -v test2 | xargs rm -rf
```

Then 'ls' output is :

```
test2
```

EDIT:

Thanks for the comment. If the directory contains some files with spaces :

```
mkdir test && cd test
touch "test 1"
touch "test 2"
touch "test 3"
touch "test 4"
touch "test 5"
```

You can use (with bash) :

```
rm !("test 1"|"test 4")
```

'ls' output :

```
test 1
test 4
```

Comment: Was going to do very similar using find, but yours works and you were faster. +1

Comment: this fails if you have files with spaces in their names.

Comment: To handle filenames with spaces one could use `ls -1 | grep -v do_not_delete | xargs -I files rm "files"`

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you're using the bash shell (the most common case), you can use the negation globbing (pathname expansion) symbol:

```
rm -rf !(myfile.txt)
```

This uses extended globbing, so you would need to enable this first:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 cp myfile.txt somewhere_else;
 rm -rf *
 cp somewhere_else/myfile.txt .
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ln myfile.txt .myfile.txt && rm -rf * && mv .myfile.txt myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This page gives a variety of options depending on the shell:
http://www.unix.com/unix-dummies-questions-answers/51400-how-remove-all-except-one-file.html

Answer (score 0):

For a recursive `rm` you'd need to do the recursion with `find` and exclude the file(s) you wanted to keep (or `grep`, but that can get you into whitespace trouble).  For a shell glob, modern shells have glob patterns that can be used to exclude files; this can be combined with shell-level glob recursion when available (e.g. `zsh` has `rm **/*~foo/bar` — note that this is likely to run into argument length limits for large directory trees).