# Delete all file except some in bash, without cd to the directory?

Tags: linux, bash, script, rm

I need to make a daily cleanup in a download directory.

I have saw [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/264534/how-to-delete-all-but-one-file-in-unix) and tested the answer

```
rm !("test 1"|"test 4")
```

It work great, but require to have cd to the directory before. Since my app need to be two direcltory higher in many part, I d like to don t have to make something like

```
cd /app/download
rm !("test 1"|"test 4")
cd ../..
```

I have tried

```
rm !("./app/download/test 1"|"./app/download/test 4")
```

But well, it delete the content of the higher directory, not download/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there:

```
shopt -s extglob   # ← Only needed if you haven't enabled it yet
rm ./app/download/!("test 1"|"test 4")
```

The `!(…)` will be expanded with the full path to all files except the ones in `!(…)`. Since you prefix the arguments to `rm` with the path `./app/download/`, no other files higher than that directory will be deleted.